# Dart typedef with generics causing subtype error

Tags: dart

Note: I've completely re-written the question as I know have a complete piece of code the reproduces the problem.

The following code fails with:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '(OnBadAir) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(Event) => bool'
#0      Fork._dispatch
typedef.dart:33
#1      main
```

This is extracted from the fsm2 package.

Because the 'dispatch' event is processing a queue of events that have different event types the dispatch event can't be typed and we then run into the problem with typedefs being contravariant(as pointed out by @Lrn).

So the question is how do I pass a 'condition' into the event queue that can be processed by the dispatcher?

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class Event {}

class OnBadAir extends Event {
  OnBadAir(this.quality);
  int quality;
}

typedef GuardCondition<E extends Event> = bool Function(E event);

class _QueuedEvent {
  _QueuedEvent(this.event);
  Event event;
}

class Fork<E extends Event> {
  Fork(this.td);

  TransitionDefinition td;
  final _eventQueue = <_QueuedEvent>[];

  void queue(E event) {
    _eventQueue.add(_QueuedEvent(event));
  }

  /// dequeue the next event and transition it.
  Future<void> _dispatch() async {
    assert(_eventQueue.isNotEmpty, 'The event queue is in an invalid state');
    final event = _eventQueue.first;

    /// crashes here.
    if (td.condition(event.event)) {
      print('it worked');
    }
  }
}

class TransitionDefinition<E extends Event> {
  TransitionDefinition({required this.condition});
  final GuardCondition<E> condition;
}

void main() async {
  final fork = Fork<OnBadAir>(
      TransitionDefinition<OnBadAir>(condition: (e) => e.quality < 10))
    ..queue(OnBadAir(10));

  await fork._dispatch();
}
```

Comment: The `GuardCondition<E>` `typedef` isn't used in the code you've shown.  Please post a minimal but complete example that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jamesdlin - updated with code sample the reproduces the problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you have `Fork<E extends Event>` that internally uses `TransitionDefinition` (which is shorthand for `TransitionDefinition<Event>`) instead of `TransitionDefinition<E>`.  Once you fix that, you can do `if (td.condition(event.event as E))`, and your code will work (after adjusting your condition to return `true` for the queued event).  If it's possible that the queued event might be a different type of `Event` that is not an `E`, you can check `event is E` first.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have declared `TransitionDefinition` as something like:

```dart
class TransitionDefinition<E extends Event> {
  final GuardDefinition<E> condition;
  // ...
}
```

and that `td` actually is an instance with type `TransitionDefinition<OnBadAir>`.

However, for some reason, the `_evaluateConditions(td, OnBadAir(5));`
infers a type argument to `_evaluateConditions` of `<Event>`,
so that `td` inside `_evaluateConditions` has a static type of `TransitionDefinition<Event>` (`TransitionDefinition<E>` with `E` dynamically bound to `Event`).

That means that when you get to the expression `td.condition`,
the code expects a `bool Function(Event)`.
Since the type argument to the class occurs *contravariantly* in `condition`, but class generics are covariant, the compiler cannot assume that the runtime value is a `bool Function(Event)`. So it inserts a check.

That check fails, because the actual type is `bool Function(OnBadAir)`, which is-not-a `bool Function(Event)`. The former cannot be called with all the same arguments as the latter, which is part of what we require of a subtype.
That's why you get a runtime error.

If you can do the call as  `_evaluateConditions<OnBadAir>(td, OnBadAir(5));` instead, the error might go away.

In general, using a class's type parameter in a function-typed field or return type as a *parameter* (in contravariant position) type, is unsafe.
If you up-cast such a class instance to a supertype, and try to access the field, it may throw. For your own protection, since the value would not have been sound, it would not have had a type that is a subtype of the statically expected type of that expression.

Comment: thanks for the response and I believe I understand your answer - typedefs are contravariant. I've written the question with code that demonstrates the problem. The question remains: how do I pass the test function through the queue?

Comment: @BrettSutton Did you end up finding a workaround or alternative solution? I have an use case which is having the same issue with this pattern.